# BigQuery error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, datasource, looker-studio

I am trying to connect a Data Studio report to a table and to a view from BigQuery.
In BigQuery the table receives the data from a GoogleSheet that is located in my Drive, the view is querying this same table but adds some new fields.
When I try to connect my chart to one of theses data sources I get the following error:

*BigQuery error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.*

What's the cause? What should I do to fix that ?

I'm precising that I am the owner of the sheet, the project in BigQuery, and of the DS Report.

Thank you

Comment: If you are using a service account the account needs the oauth scope  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly

Comment: @Cyrusc Where do you set this oauth ? In the admin console of the domain ? in IAM ? thank you

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

Go to the Data studio report and add a new data source. Choose the Google Sheets connector. This should open a new page where you can Authorize Data studio to connect to Google sheets. You don't have to actually create the data source, but that is the only way I found where you can authorize Data studio to connect to sheets. I believe this is required to access sheets data even through a Bigquery external table.

Comment: this is the solution.  would be nice if error was more specific.  now i need to rollback iam permissions.  note that you need to add the service account in the sheet permissions too